# Secure plaintext passwords on a database

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, password-protection, password-encryption

For internal reasons I need to store passwords for 3rd party accounts in a database so I cannot really use a hash because I wouldn't be able to recover the password easily from that.

Is there a way to encrypt the plaintext password so a potential hacker couldn't easily retrieve the password even if he had the mysql table but I can still decrypt it to see its original form?

Comment: Why do you need to be able to recover the password?!

Comment: Read this: https://www.troyhunt.com/lessons-in-website-security-anti/

Comment: Because these are accounts on a 3rd party website and I need to be able to log into them when needed.

Comment: You absolute don't need to log in into accounts of strangers. I absolutely wouldn't want that. If you can decrypt the passwords, then the hacker can that too. Safely storing passwords is only possible by hashing them (with a strong hashing algorithm, like BCrypt or Argon2i).

Comment: Please don't assume everybody is a criminal! I only want to create my own password manager for critical accounts since I don't trust others like lastpass there. Since they are storing plaintext passwords securely it has to be possible.

Comment: It's not an assumption that everyone is a criminal.  The assumption -- usually correct -- is that when someone says they "need" to be able to store passwords encrypted, the are making excuses based on unsupportable assertions.  In this case, if you are talking about encrypting *your* passwords to other sites so that they can be stored securely, you have a valid justification for storing the passwords encrypted... but this isn't clear from your question and we see the other sort of question too frequently.

Answer (score 1):

It's not best practice to decrypt the passwords. But if your requirement is that **than simply use any encryption or decrypt method of string.**

I recently used below function to encrypt or decrypt string.  For securing URL. You can also use this encrypt or decrypt function for securing the url while using GET method requests.

```
<?php
define("ENCRYPTION_KEY", "ABCDEFGHIJKLabcdefghijklm!@#$%^&*");
$string = "Plain Text";

echo $encrypted = encrypt($string, ENCRYPTION_KEY);
echo "<br />";
echo $decrypted = decrypt($encrypted, ENCRYPTION_KEY);

// this function will return encrypted string
function encrypt($pure_string, $encryption_key) {
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, utf8_encode($pure_string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return $encrypted_string;
}

// this function will return encrypted string
function decrypt($encrypted_string, $encryption_key) {
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $encryption_key, $encrypted_string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return $decrypted_string;
}
?>
```

> So for Your purpose using this encrypted function store plain text  in database
>   and retrieve it using another function.

Comment: The ECB mode is actually never a good choice, it doesn't use an IV at all so the result of `mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)` will always be zero.

Comment: what would you suggest to use?